# Resolving Domains to IPs

Tags: command-line, dns, ip

I have a file full of subdomains each line. And I want to convert these subdomains to IPs by using bash script. my file:

```
 subdomain1.example.com
 subdomain2.example.com
 ...
```

and I want a new file full of IPs of these.

I want to do this with a loop.

```
for line in $(cat subdomains.txt)
    do
   .......
done < ip.txt
```

What should that be in `........` part?

Comment: See `man nslookup` or `man host` or `man dig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With single `awk` command:

```
awk '{cmd="host "$0; cmd|getline $0; print $1,$NF;close(cmd)}' infile
```

**Explanation:**

Here we set a shell command as `host $0` and assign to a variable called `cmd`. Then with `cmd |getline $0` we call that command [Using getline from a Pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fPipe) which `awk` passes the line from input `infile` file to the `cmd`, then print the first and last fields (domain& IP). At the end we need to close the command we opened, so we used [`close(cmd)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html) to close it.

**Input:**

```
askubuntu.com
stackexchange.com
```

**Result:**

```
askubuntu.com 11.22.33.44
stackexchange.com 55.66.77.88
```

Comment: Should I do in loop? I just get so many HOST 3 (NTDOMAİN) line

Comment: No, just do `awk '{cmd="host "$0; cmd|getline $0; print $1,$NF;close(cmd)}' subdomains.txt`.

Comment: I get same result HOST 3 (NTDOMAIN)...

Comment: AFAIK, that means that domain doesn't exist. or there is empty /whitespaces line in your subdomains.txt file?

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
for line in $(cat subdomains.txt); do
     nslookup $line | grep Address | grep -v "#53" | awk {'print $2'} >> ips.txt
done
```